# Python Sklearn / Scikit & cx_freeze: module 'sklearn.tree._criterion' has no attribute 'Criterion'

Tags: python, module, scikit-learn, cx-freeze, imblearn

I am currently trying to put a Python app, which uses **Sklearn modules**, in a stand-alone `.exe` file.

My current `cx_freeze` `setup.py` looks like this:

```
import os
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable

base = "Win32GUI"

os.environ['TCL_LIBRARY'] = r'C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\tcl\tcl8.6'
os.environ['TK_LIBRARY'] = r'C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\tcl\tk8.6'

executables = [Executable("gui_handler.py", base=base)]

packages = ["idna", "numpy", "sklearn", "nltk", "stop_words", "scipy", "scipy.sparse.csgraph._validation",
            "scipy.spatial.ckdtree", "PyQt5", "imblearn.under_sampling", "imblearn.over_sampling",
            "sklearn.tree._criterion"]

options = {
    'build_exe': {
        "packages": packages,
        "excludes": ["scipy.spatial.cKDTree"],
        "zip_include_packages": ["sklearn", "nltk", "idna"] # PyQt5 zippen verschlechtert die Optik
    },
}

setup(
    name="<any name>",
    options=options,
    version="1.0",
    description='<any description>',
    executables=executables
)
```

It worked fine before but the latest version of my application uses the **module imblearn**. I think it causes this problem (appears a few seconds after double-clicking the `.exe` file):

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\initscripts\__startup__.py", line 14, in run
    module.run()
  File "C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\initscripts\Console.py", line 26, in run
    exec(code, m.__dict__)
  File "gui_handler.py", line 8, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\...\Documents\PycharmProjects\MachineLearning\build\exe.win-amd64-3.6\TextClassification\init_predict.py", line 16, in <module>
    from imblearn.under_sampling import RandomUnderSampler
  File "C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\imblearn\under_sampling\__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    from .prototype_generation import ClusterCentroids
  File "C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\imblearn\under_sampling\prototype_generation\__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    from .cluster_centroids import ClusterCentroids
  File "C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\imblearn\under_sampling\prototype_generation\cluster_centroids.py", line 14, in <module>
    from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 656, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 626, in _load_backward_compatible
  File "C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\cluster\__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    from .spectral import spectral_clustering, SpectralClustering
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 656, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 626, in _load_backward_compatible
  File "C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\cluster\spectral.py", line 17, in <module>
    from ..manifold import spectral_embedding
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 656, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 626, in _load_backward_compatible
  File "C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\manifold\__init__.py", line 9, in <module>
    from .t_sne import TSNE
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 656, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 626, in _load_backward_compatible
  File "C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\manifold\t_sne.py", line 25, in <module>
    from . import _barnes_hut_tsne
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 656, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 626, in _load_backward_compatible
  File "ExtensionLoader_sklearn_manifold__barnes_hut_tsne.py", line 23, in <module>
  File "ExtensionLoader_sklearn_manifold__barnes_hut_tsne.py", line 15, in __bootstrap__
  File "C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\imp.py", line 343, in load_dynamic
    return _load(spec)
  File "sklearn\neighbors\quad_tree.pxd", line 54, in init sklearn.manifold._barnes_hut_tsne
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 656, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 626, in _load_backward_compatible
  File "ExtensionLoader_sklearn_neighbors_quad_tree.py", line 23, in <module>
  File "ExtensionLoader_sklearn_neighbors_quad_tree.py", line 15, in __bootstrap__
  File "C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\imp.py", line 343, in load_dynamic
    return _load(spec)
  File "sklearn\tree\_criterion.pxd", line 21, in init sklearn.neighbors.quad_tree
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 656, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 626, in _load_backward_compatible
  File "C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\tree\__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    from .tree import DecisionTreeClassifier
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 656, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 626, in _load_backward_compatible
  File "C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\tree\tree.py", line 40, in <module>
    from ._criterion import Criterion
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 656, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 626, in _load_backward_compatible
  File "ExtensionLoader_sklearn_tree__criterion.py", line 23, in <module>
  File "ExtensionLoader_sklearn_tree__criterion.py", line 15, in __bootstrap__
  File "C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\imp.py", line 343, in load_dynamic
    return _load(spec)
  File "sklearn\tree\_splitter.pxd", line 34, in init sklearn.tree._criterion
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 656, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 626, in _load_backward_compatible
  File "ExtensionLoader_sklearn_tree__splitter.py", line 23, in <module>
  File "ExtensionLoader_sklearn_tree__splitter.py", line 15, in __bootstrap__
  File "C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\imp.py", line 343, in load_dynamic
    return _load(spec)
  File "sklearn\tree\_criterion.pxd", line 21, in init sklearn.tree._splitter
AttributeError: module 'sklearn.tree._criterion' has no attribute 'Criterion'
```

I took a look in the `sklearn\tree\tree.py` file and there is indeed this import statement:

```
from ._criterion import Criterion
```

The same folder contains the files:

`_criterion.cp36-win_amd64.pyd`
`_splitter.cp36-win_amd64.pyd`
`_tree.cp36-win_amd64.pyd`
`_utils.cp36-win_amd64.pyd`

which are python module files as far as I know.

The application runs perfectly fine if I execute it from the **PyCharm IDE** so I would either assume that my program doesn't even need the **Criterion module** (and `cx_freeze` just loads it because it loads everything) and therefore I don't get the error message at runtime. Or that the module is actually missing.

Any ideas what could fix this problem?

Comment: Please, only use code brackets for codes.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I fixed the problem myself.

I just removed the line

```
zip_include_packages": ["sklearn", "nltk", "idna"]
```

from my `cx_freeze_setup.py`.